# What is smart casting and when should I use it?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Smartly using smart casting](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26246/smartly-using-smart-casting)

Is there a key to smart casting? Are there characters for which smart casting is viable and others aren't?

I have been wondering always about how to smartcast a spell on League. I know some abilities such as Karthus and Cassiopeia Q's are auto smartcast, but is there a quick way of doing it for the rest? I always heard about it but never learned how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you hold the shift button and press the spells keybind for an example on amumu's bandage toss its Q

so if you hold shift and press Q it will automatically use the spell in the direction the cursor is.

this works with all spells that aren't already automatic.

It is good to always use smart casts if possible but if you make a mistake you will pay for it that is why its best to only use it on less risky abilities.