# What is Auto-casting in LoL?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Smartly using smart casting](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26246/smartly-using-smart-casting)

I've been hearing a lot of people talking about auto-casting. I was wondering how does it work and how do you set it up?

Answer (score 4):

I think you mean smart casting, which is when you cast a spell and it instantly happens. When you don't have smart casting on, you will get a range indicator and will need to click twice. Once to activate the ability, the other to cast it.

While using smart cast, the ability goes off the instant you click, assuming you are in range for that ability. If you are not, your summoner will run to the maximum range required and will use the ability when they can. If you are smart casting a skill shot, the spell will go off in its regular line, but will go to where your cursor is.

Smart casting is a way to get abilities off quicker and more reliably. You can turn them on in the Key Bindings section but you will either need to set hot keys, such as SHIFT + Q, or take off all normal casting, and turn on Smart Cast Q.

This video might help you understand:

Comment: This cleared up a bit