# What is smartcast?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Smartly using smart casting](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26246/smartly-using-smart-casting)

when I browse to League of Legends forums I see a lot of guys playing with "Smartcast". What is this? Can someone explain me this and how can I use it?

Thanks!!

Max

Answer (score 1):

**[Source (League of Legends wiki)](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Smart_cast)**

> Smart cast automatically casts the selected ability at (or towards)
>   the current mouse cursor position as if you had first pressed the
>   ability button and then left-clicked at the target position. Smart
>   cast works for self-buff abilities, targeted abilities,
>   ground-targeted abilities and skillshots. Smart casting a support buff
>   ability (an ability that can be cast on self e.g. a shield or a heal)
>   when the cursor is on an invalid target will self-cast the ability
>   instead. Note that you can use self-casting to self-cast support buff
>   abilities regardless of cursor location. Using smart cast can be
>   invaluable because it reduces the time delay between activating and
>   casting by cutting the user input in half; activate vs activate and
>   click.   Remember that smart casting means you don't get the targeting
>   graphic, which can make it harder to accurately aim skillshots. They
>   will fire instantly, instead of showing the skillshot for fine tuning
>   the shot. However, there is an option to turn range indicators on,
>   which will show the targeting graphic while the ability key is
>   depressed. This can also be helpful because the ability can then be
>   canceled by right-clicking.

**Long story short**, abilities that normally would require to press the shortcut button (Q,W,E,R) is launched immediatly, without the display of targeting graphics (skillshot arrows or range indicators).

You can easily set all abilities to smartcast by going to the keybindings menu and looking up options such as "Smartcast ability 1, ability 2 etc." and switching them to your normal ability keys - Q,W,E,R.

Some examples are:

- Morgana's dark binding gives an aiming arrow, so it's not a smartcast
- Urgot's Acid Hunter launches the projectile directly at your cursor
  as soon as you press "Q", and is a built in smartcast.
- Karthus' Lay Waste places a delayed blast at your cursor without any mouse clicks or indicators, and is thus a smartcast.

*Note: After some not-too-old patch, you can see the aim-helpers on (manually set) smartcast abilities while you are holding down the ability key.

Answer (score 0):

smartcasted skills are used right away the moment you press the skill key without the need to click the mouse additionally

you can use it either with shift+skillkey or change the key in the key bindings

Answer (score 0):

Smart cast allows your champion to use a spell just by clicking on the skill button.

Whomever your mouse is highlighting the spell will be cast on.

Where ever your mouse is pointing your skill will be cast on that spot.

Skill shots will go in the direction of your mouse.

Note* If you want self heal spells to cast on yourself with smart casting, you need to bind your keys to Smart Cast + Self Cast