# Can I somehow use QWER as smartcast and put shift+QWER to normal cast?

Tags: league-of-legends

I use smartcast, but sometimes I would like to see the spell ranges etc.

Can I somehow use QWER as smartcast and put shift+QWER to normal cast?

Comment: Have your tried looking at our [smartcast](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26246/smartly-using-smart-casting) question?  I don't play LoL, so I'm not sure if it would answer your question.

Comment: I think you can, brb I'm gonna go screenshot it.

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR No, you can't **unless** you modify a file. [Scroll to the Bottom!]

Here is me setting Smart Cast Spell 1,2,3, and 4 as Q,W,E, and R, respectively.

[image]

Now when I try to set Cast Spell 1,2,3,and 4 as [Shift]Q, [Shift]W, [Shift]E, and [Shift]R, this is the message I get.

> Cast Spell ( ) cannot be bound as specified.

[image]

Key Bindings seems to only accept numbers and letters, in addition to some symbols.

So it seems there's actually a way to switch smartcast and normal cast. Found this from http://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/o09bn/modify_smartcast_to_qwer_and_normal_cast_to/

- **Note: For this to work, you must have modified your key bindings in the past.**
- Go to `C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\Config` (Unless you have saved League of Legends in a different file)
- Erase what you see in "Config" and paste in the following

  ```
  evtCastSpell1=[Shift][q]
  evtCastSpell2=[Shift][w]
  evtCastSpell3=[Shift][e]
  evtCastSpell4=[Shift][r]
  evtCastAvatarSpell1=[Shift][d]
  evtCastAvatarSpell2=[Shift][f]
  evtSmartCastSpell1=[q]
  evtSmartCastSpell2=[w]
  evtSmartCastSpell3=[e]
  evtSmartCastSpell4=[r]
  evtSmartCastAvatarSpell1=[d]
  evtSmartCastAvatarSpell2=[f]
  ```
- Test it out in a custom game before heading to normals/ranked with your new settings. If you don't want to smartcast your 'AvatarSpells' or Summoner Spells, rather, don't paste in the last two lines.

Comment: Well didn't he ask if he could switch shift+qwer with qwer? because that's how i'm playing right now

Comment: "Can I somehow use QWER as smartcast and put shift+QWER to normal cast?" He wants to activate normal cast with Shift.

Comment: And he states in the question that he already uses smartcast :)

Answer (score 0):

You can rebind the spell cast keys exactly like you are requesting in the keybind